# Unity 2d Bouncing off wall Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to move a ball on scene. The ball begins to move in a random position, then collides with an object containing the Collider2D, the ball changes its position and goes in another direction.

```
  public float MoveSpeed;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = RandomVector(-5f, 5f);
    transform.gameObject.GetOrAddComponent<ColliderEventSystem>().ColliderEntered += PushObject;
}

private void PushObject(ColliderEventSystem eventTarget, Collider2D other)
{
    float speed = 100;
    Vector3 direction = (transform.position - other.transform.position).normalized;
    rb.AddForce((direction * speed));
}

private Vector3 RandomVector(float min, float max)
{
    var x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max);
    var y = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max);
    return new Vector3(x, y);
}
```

Something is wrong in the code because the object changes its position but does not move as it should.
[image]

The picture shows how the ball should move!

Comment: It looks like you have to get the `IncidentAngle` of the player with the wall then set the angle multiplied by `-1` as the `reflectedAngle`.

Comment: what do you mean, I do not understand

Comment: You mean you need something like a bouncing effect?Right?

Comment: yes, something like that at the Pong Game, but I just need what the ball does

Comment: You have to see [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70294/get-gameobject-to-bounce-of-colliders) although it is [duplicate] you can see the answer of that question too.